# Is there a way to read and validate specified PDF text using ITextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to create a concept program where I can read a PDF, and have it validate that a specific string or sentence exists using ITextSharp. The following code snippet is what I have so far:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System;
using System.Text;


namespace PDFReader
{
    internal class Class1
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\Me\Downloads\TestPDF.pdf"))

                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

So far, this works wonderfully for reading the full PDF contents, but I need it to return the specified string, if it exists. I was thinking something like this:

```
.Where(p => p.Text.Contains("SpecifiedStringHere")).OrderBy(p => p.Y).Reverse().ToList();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please specify more clearly what you are looking for. You say you *need it to return the specified string* but in your *something like this* code snipplet you do **not** *return the specified string* but instead you return a list of some unknown object type with a `Text` and a `Y` property where the `Text` property value *contains* the specified string. What object type shall that be? What shall it contain?

Comment: Hi, the second code snippet was just an example of something I am looking for, I appreciate it's probably not correct. I would like to be able to enter a string in something like 'Text.Contains', then the program reads the PDF file, and displays the corresponding text to console if finds it within the PDF.

Comment: *"I would like to be able to enter a string in something like 'Text.Contains'"* - well, what about the `StringBuilder text` in your code, you can do `text.ToString().Contains`.

Answer (score -2):

There is a solution ,not so elegant ,but working one

```
public bool IsValidPdf(string fileName)
{
   try
   {
      new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fileName);
      return true;
   }
   catch (iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: The op wants to validate that a certain text is in the given pdf. They implicitly assume that they can load the pdf.

Comment: So that means search not a validation

Comment: Essentially yes. People asking questions here unfortunately often do so using a sloppy language.